# android asynctask edittext

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I  have a piece of code that querys my webserver xml parses the data that comes back and fills textfields on my GUi with the relevant data.  Before i had this within my oncreate function and the code worked fine.  However i wanted to show a loading dialogue to the user so i moved the web server and xml parsing operatons to an asynctask.  The problem rises now when i go to populate my GUI text fields with my parsed data and i get an error thrown.  Can anyone see what i am  doing wrong

```
new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute();   /// called from the oncreate function
```

and my background task code is as follows

```
  public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends
AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
int myProgress;

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
MyDialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
 MyDialog = ProgressDialog.show(attraction_more_info.this, " " , " Loading. Please wait ... ", true);

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

              xml query and parse stuff on here ...


    // Populate page now

    TextView titlefield = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.att_title);
    TextView add1field = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.att_address1);
    TextView add2field = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.att_address2);
    TextView townfield = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.att_town);
    TextView postcodefield = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.att_postcode);
     TextView phonefield = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.att_phone);
     WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

              MY ERRORS START HERE
    titlefield.setText(attraction_name);
    add1field.setText(attraction_address1);
    add2field.setText(attraction_address2);
    townfield.setText(attraction_town);
    postcodefield.setText(attraction_postcode);
    phonefield.setText(attraction_phone);
    webview.loadData(attraction_description, "text/html", null);

return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
}

}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Haven't read your code yet, but what's the error and where does it occur? Please provide the log.

Answer (score 4):

You can't update UI elements from a non-UI thread.  Try moving all the setText() calls and webview.loadData() to onPostExecute()

you'll have to save the query results in the class object to do that

Comment: But we have read that we can update UI from asynchronous task.UI update is only not possible in Thread.

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad You can update UI from asynchronous task from methods other than doInBackground() (or called from doInBackground())  doInBackground runs in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
add1field.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {             
        add1field.setText(attraction_address1);
    }
});
```